# HTTP request on JMeter test failure

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter test, if there is any error, I want to trigger HTTP request to post a message on my system for further attention. What can I do here? Mail visualiser works fine to report errors over email. I want to do the same but over HTTP request. I am using jmeter 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

1. Add [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) after the HTTP Request sampler and put the following code into "Condition" area:

   ```
   `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`
   ```
2. Add [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) as a child of the If Controller and configure your email server details, credentials, message, etc. there - see [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more details.

`JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` is a [pre-defined JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) holding the result of previous sampler execution, it is `true` if previous sampler is successful and `false` otherwise. Due to the If Controller the SMTP Request sampler will only be executed in case of HTTP Request sampler failure which seems to be something you're looking for.

Comment: I wanted to send HTTP request on overall result of the test. Following on with your inputs i was able to create a solution to store the state of the test result as property using beanshell processor and use it in teardown thread group to send HTTP request. Thanks!