# How to track if any of the JMeter request fails in a thread?

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a JMeter test plan with multiple HTTP requests.

To track request which failed, [got answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037002/http-request-on-jmeter-test-failure) about using `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok`.

As there are multiple requests I need to add this `Beanshell sampler` after each of the HTTP request to flag off failed request.

Is there a way to set a flag if any of the HTTP request fails in a given thread?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `BeanShell Listener` or `JSR223 Listener` and add your code for failure under the if statement:

```
if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "false") {
   ....

}
```

JSR223 Listener will execute code after each Sampler and check if failed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need the Sampler, you need the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners). Listeners are obeying [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) therefore if you put a listener at the same level as all your requests (or higher) it will be applied to all of them.
2. You don't need Beanshell, it is a kind of performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any scripting tasks. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information, benchmarks, Groovy best practices, etc.

Example code you could use would be something like:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    log.info(sampler.getThreadName() + ' ' + sampler.getName() + ' has failed') 
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Listener]